# zooming using matplotlib arrows

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to draw an arrow between two (scatter) nodes in matplotlib. I  tried to draw it using a [connection patch](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch) using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nodes = ax.scatter([1,2], [3,2], s=300)
arrow = mpl.patches.ConnectionPatch((1,3),(2,2), "data", "data", arrowstyle="-|>", shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5, mutation_scale=20, fc="w")
ax.add_patch(arrow)
fig.show()
```

To get:

[image]

Which looks OK. However, when I zoom on one of the nodes, the arrow disappears:
[image]

When I use a [fancy arrow patch](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch) with the following (similar) code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nodes = ax.scatter([1,2], [3,2], s=300)
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((1,3), (2,2), arrowstyle='-|>', shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5, mutation_scale=20, fc='w')
ax.add_patch(arrow)
plt.show()
```

I get the same plot but zooming  is possible:

[image]

Can someone explain why this is not happening using a `ConnectionPatch`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is steered by the `_annotation_clip` property of the `ConnectionPatch`. Usually when showing an arrow between two parts of a figure you would not want to show an arrow if one of the parts to be connected lies outside the visible range. This motivates why `_annotation_clip` is set to `True` by default.

If you still want to use a `ConnectionPatch` and show the arrow, even if one of the points is outside the axes, you may set that property to `False`,

```
arrow.set_annotation_clip(False)
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nodes = ax.scatter([1,2], [3,2], s=300)
arrow = mpl.patches.ConnectionPatch((1,3),(2,2), "data", "data", clip_on=True,
                    arrowstyle="-|>", shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5, mutation_scale=20, fc="w")
arrow.set_annotation_clip(False)

ax.add_patch(arrow)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that using a `ConnectionPatch` when both arguments `coordsA` and `coordsB` are set to `"data"` is in principle the same as using a `FancyArrowPatch` since `ConnectionPatch` subclasses `FancyArrowPatch` to provide other transforms and also mixed transforms.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Maybe you can help me by taking a look at [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383130/proper-mutational-scale-value-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: do you know if something a little different from the above is possible? I'd like to draw arrows in my plots, iif there is enough size for the arrow to be displayed properly (ie, with arrow and tail in the right position). Further if I zoom in or zoom out the plot, I'd like the arrow to appear or disappear, given the above condition. (I posted this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305075/how-to-control-matplotlib-annotate-arrow-more-specifically-in-terms-of-size-of )