# Proper Mutational scale value in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was wondering for the purpose of key argument `mutational_scale` in `matplotlib`; in the case of `matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch` which is used to plot an arrow, `mutational_scale` is set to `1` by default. From the docs:

> scalar, optional (default: 1)
>
> Value with which attributes of arrowstyle (e.g., head_length) will be scaled.

When I plot an arrow between two scatter points of size 300, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([0,1],[0,1], s=300)
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0), (1,1), arrowstyle='-|>')
plt.show()
```

The arrow head is non-visible.

[image]

However, when I use:

```
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0), (1,1), arrowstyle='-|>', mutational_aspect=20)
```

I get the proper arrow.
[image]

My guess is that the overall figure is scaled by a factor larger than 1, closer to 20, making the arrow head invisible with a mutational scale of 1 but visible when using 20. But it's just a guess.

If so, is there a way to know the mutation scaling of the overall figure  to decide the proper  scaling value for the arrow head?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [annotating-with-arrow](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html#annotating-with-arrow) subsection
in the documentation the `arrowstyle` parameters are presented. For the `-|>` style it says

> `-|>` head_length=0.4,head_width=0.2

This means that the head of the arrow is `0.4*mutation_scale` long and `2*0.2*mutation_scale` wide. The units are points.

Since `FancyArrowPatch`es are designed to be used with annotations, the mutation scale would be set to the fontsize in points when drawing an annotation. E.g. for a 15 pt fontsize, `mutation_scale=15`.

When using a `FancyArrowPatch` on it's own one hence set the desired size in points

```
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,1), (1,1), arrowstyle='-|>', mutation_scale=15)
```

This will create an arrow with full arrow head width `2*0.2*15=6` points.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
ax.set_xlim([-0.6,5])
for i in [5,10,15,20,25]:
    ax.scatter([0,1],[i,i], s=(2*.2*i)**2)
    arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,i), (1,i), arrowstyle='-|>',
                                        mutation_scale=i)
    ax.add_patch(arrow)
    ax.text(1.2,i,"mutation_scale = {}".format(i), 
            va="center")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can specify the head_length and head_width in points directly,

```
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,1), (1,1),
                    arrowstyle='-|>,head_width=3,head_length=6')
```

The following would hence produce the same image as above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
ax.set_xlim([-0.6,5])
for i in [5,10,15,20,25]:
    ax.scatter([0,1],[i,i], s=(2*.2*i)**2)
    arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,i), (1,i), 
                        arrowstyle='-|>,head_width={},head_length={}'.format(i/5.,.4*i))
    ax.add_patch(arrow)
    ax.text(1.2,i,"mutation_scale = {}".format(i), 
            va="center")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is `2*0.2*mutation_scale` a typo (`0.2*mutation_scale`, instead)? Or why the factor of `2` for the width of the arrow?

Comment: 0.2 is the half width of the arrow, so the arrow head is 2*0.2 wide.