# How to control matplotlib annotate (arrow more specifically) in terms of size of figure?

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to draw arrows in my plots, iif there is enough size for the arrow to be displayed properly (ie, with arrow and tail in the right position). Is there any way to control this in code?

For a better explanations, here is the problem explained in 3 examples: in this 1st figure, the arrow shouldn't be displayed as the arrow should go from the dotted line to the solid black line, and in this case there is not enough space for a proper visualisation.

[image]

When the same image is zoomed, the arrow behaves correctly though:
[image]

Here goes a final example, with a figure in its normal size (without zoom) where the arrow behaves correctly and should be drawn.[image]

In conclusion, in case 1 I would like the arrow not to be drawn (not enough space for a correct visualisation) and to be drawn in the other cases.

Comment: How about using an `if else` to judge the distance between start point and end point.

Comment: That won't work(afaik) as it depends on the actual rendered size (how it's seen on screen, with zoom or not) and not on the data size